# NER Named Entity Recognition using LLMs Like tranF5 or LLAMA2

Tags: named-entity-recognition, llm

I am trying to do NER (Named entity recognition) using Large language models like Trans-F5 or LLAMA2. Till now, I found the ways of using prompt engineering. Which means we need to specify what to find in the text.
Can we fine tune and use these LLMs using the old NER techniques, like providing the label for entity and then doing inference phase to find the entity value.
Any code reference would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dataset Should Something Look like this for LLAMA2

```
{
  "instruction": "What is world of warcraft",
  "context": "",
  "response": "World of warcraft is a massive online multi player role playing game. It was released in 2004 by bizarre entertainment"
}
```

https://www.philschmid.de/sagemaker-llama2-qlora

You can use the below link to fine tune a LAMA2 on AWS Sagemaker

Comment: thanks for finetuning tutorial, but I am looking for spacy type annotation and then NER on it using Llama